# Calculating the length of a run in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a dataset from a logging app. It logs the time and whether my widget was OK:

```
CREATE TABLE runs (time int, ok int);

INSERT INTO runs VALUES
(1, NULL),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 1),
(5, NULL),
(6, NULL),
(7, 1),
(8, 1),
(9, NULL),
(10, 1)
```

I'd like to use a window function (I think) to determine the length of these runs of "ok"-ness. So the end dataset should look like:

```
time | ok_length
----------------
 2   |   3
 7   |   2
 10  |   1
```

This is as far as I've got:

```
SELECT
  time,
  ok,
  CASE WHEN
    LAG(ok) OVER (ORDER BY time) IS NOT null
    THEN SUM(ok) OVER (ORDER BY time) END
FROM runs
ORDER BY time
```

But its totally wrong. Can anyone help? Perhaps I have to do something with a frame at the end of the window function, but that frame would have to have a conditional to stop when it reaches a NULL.
Here's the SQL fiddle I'm working with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/98bf4/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are ways to simplify this but these types of counting based on values queries are always a bit verbose.  The main pieces are:

- `group_start_cte` - lag to flag the rows that are the start of a different logical grouping.
- `group_cte` - cumulative sum to give all the rows a group id.
- `group_cnt` - count that partitions by the logical grouping id.
- `first_time_for_group` - get the time at the start of the group.

And then at the end we bring `group_cnt` and `first_time_for_group` together:

```
WITH
group_start_cte AS (
SELECT
    TIME,
    ok,
    CASE
      WHEN LAG(ok) OVER (ORDER BY TIME asc) is distinct from ok
      THEN TRUE
    END AS group_start
FROM
    runs
),
group_cte AS (
SELECT
    TIME,
    ok,
    group_start,
    SUM(CASE WHEN group_start THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY TIME asc) AS grp_id
FROM
    group_start_cte
),
first_time_for_group as (
SELECT
    time,
    grp_id
FROM
    group_cte
WHERE
    group_start IS TRUE
),
group_cnt AS (
SELECT
    grp_id,
    count(*) AS ok_length
FROM
    group_cte
WHERE
    ok IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    grp_id
)
SELECT
    TIME,
    ok_length
FROM
    group_cnt
    LEFT JOIN first_time_for_group
    USING (grp_id)
ORDER BY
    time ASC
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit less verbose solution:

```
select distinct
        min(time) over (partition by gp)
        , sum(ok) over (partition by gp)
from (
        select *
                , time - row_number() over (partition by ok order by time asc) gp
        from runs
        where ok is not null
) rs
order by 1
```